# Product of Homomorphisms

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-homomorphism

I was wondering for a group of homomorphisms from G to an abelian group H (Hom(G,H)) what the group operation was. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$f*g$ is defined by $(f*g)(x) = f(x)+g(x)$